# Coding of the button in the picture

Tags: css

I was wondering how I would be able to style a button into having the drop-shadow in the bottom right of the button.

Haven’t coded in a while, and never really have been good with the design aspect.

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image: button with shadow offset to the lower left]

Comment: The link to the picture: https://i.imgur.com/QdO7eMg.png

Answer (score 1):

So something like this?

```css
body {background: black;}


#btn{
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 0px white);
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#btn:active {
 background: #eceff1;  
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">
BESTILL MAT
</button>
```